# How to build an optimal AST of a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to build a parser for regular expressions by building the abstract syntax tree from scratch (without any project dependencies or tools such as the cup parser in Java, etc). I don't want to save all the information contained in the regex but, instead, I want to simplify it as much as possible.

As an example, `x::=y|z` should lead to the same AST as the character class `x::=[yz]`. However, since regexes can (and do) get very complicated, I can't decide what equivalences to implement. For instance, I don't know how to save negative choice `x::=[^b]`, which would be equivalent to `x::=a|c|d|e|...`

What abstractions would you make? Could some of those abstractions lead to wrong ASTs later on?

Comment: You should keep character classes separate. Consider this: Unicode defines more than 120k characters, so `[^b]` would represent an alternation with roughly 120k members. That's not any good for an AST.

Answer (score 2):

An AST represents the syntax of the specific program (in OP's case, a "regex") parsed.  Usually the AST is derived from an actual parse tree, which records a specific decomposition of the input program.

OP suggests he wants an AST that represents an alternation over characters identically to a character class.  He seems to be confusing "equivalent" or "canonical" forms with specific parses.

In general, there may be different input strings, with obviously different parse trees, and identical ASTs if the decomposition is normalized. That's not always easy to do.   One may find easy cases (OP's example is sort of one of those) in which may define a canonical form for part of the language and force equivalent constructs into that canonical form.  In general, there isn't always a guarantee that you can produce a canonical from an arbitrary equivalent one.

Or you may have, as OP suggests a quandry trying to choose one: is it better to represent [^x] as the explicit set of 127 ASCII alternatives?  What should  you choose for [^<63characters>]? [^<64characters>]? [^<65characters]? What about [^x] representation in Unicode, which arguably has 2^24 characters?

As a practical matter, I suggest to OP that he produce the parse tree and/or any AST that corresponds to that parse tree.   He can then attempt to normalize the AST to a canonical form, if it makes sense to do so, but this is best kept as a separate step.